# lighttpd config file fails to parse $HTTP["url"] conditional configurations though other ones work

Tags: configuration, lighttpd

I'm trying to set mimetypes for files at a specific path on my server, which is running lighttpd version 1.4.31 with SSL.

I'm following this documentation of configuration: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration

Specifying `$PHYSICAL["path"]` isn't featured until lighttpd version 1.5.0, so I'm trying to specify `$HTTP["url"]`.

I have tried both

```
$HTTP["url"] == '/my_path/directory_to_affect/foo.html' {
     # my settings are in here  
}
```

and

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ '/my_path/directory_to_affect/*' {
     # my settings are in here  
}
```

If I test my config file with `lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf` or try to restart lighttpd, I get this error:

```
2015-04-29 14:37:52: (configfile.c.892) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 48 pos: 12 invalid character in variable name 
2015-04-29 14:37:52: (configfile.c.948) configfile parser failed at: ==
```

Or the same error but saying `=~` instead of `==`.

What's confusing me is that there are already other conditional configurations, e.g. where `$SERVER["socket"] == ":80"`, and those configurations work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [lighttpd docs on configuration file syntax](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration), only double quotes `"`, not `'` are supported.

Your observation, that `$SERVER["socket"] == ":80"` works, but `$HTTP["url"] == '/my_path/'` isn't, confirms this.